# Doing a regular list on ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

as you know in Ionic you have the list directive or the element ul with class list, but I need a regular list

this is the ionic one
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionList/

what is the best way to do it ?

```
  <li class="item item-text-wrap">
    <ul>
      <li>1. Panamá - (La Buat - Teatro Amador)</li>
      <li>2. Guatemala - (El Cine)</li>
      <li>3. Costa Rica - (Club Vertigo - Club Venue)</li>
      <li>4. Honduras</li>
      <li>5. El Salvador</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

which returns this

[image]

actually that's what I want, but I am asking because I want to know if this is the better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have that be an Ordered List, , and it will render the way you want.

Apologies if this comes out as derisive at all (it's not intentional), but... could you please ellaborate on how you ended doing AngularJS without passing through HTML first? It could be very helpful later on.